# Cause of difference of coherence distance between different light source

Tags: optics, interferometry

I was doing my first interferometry experiment today, and we had to calculate a certain beam's coherence length (the distance in which it behaves regularly). I was explained that different beams have different CLs, ranging from milimeters to kilometers, depending on the application.

However, on my ride home I started to wonder as to what exactly causes this difference in coherence length, what physical property of the light source causes this. 
What could it be?

Comment: I am pretty sure coherence length is related to the spectral width of the source. The wider the spectrum, the shorter the length. This is because the more spread out wavelength components you have, the quicker (for temporal coherence I would say quicker, for spatial coherence maybe: closer to the source) they will come out of phase relative to one another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xletmjm is spot on in his reply. Generally people speak of spatial or transverse coherence of a source to describe how much phase relationship there is between different sites on the source (if the source has a finite transverse spatial extention, like a star, or a lamp covered with a ground glass disk), and of temporal or longitudinal coherence, and it is probably the latter which you were wondering about.

It quantifies the timescale of a definite phase relationship along the propagation direction, temporally by the temporal coherence time $\tau_c$ or equivalently longitudinal/temporal coherence length $l_c = c \cdot \tau_c$.

What determines it is really the dynamics of the light generation process inside the source - like how is the phase of the emitted light field affected by the microscopic events. Extreme examples would be thermal radiation on the one end, which you can imagine as being very chaotic, and containing all kinds of wavelengths (broadband), on the other hand a high power single mode laser, where the emission process is stimulated emission. Photons undergoing stimulated emission "adopt" the phase of the stimulating light field. It is very coherent (and also spectrally narrow).

There is all kinds of intermediate cases like discharge lamps with pressure broadening (collisions with other molecules) and Doppler broadening, or simply the atomic transition's natural linewidth, determining the coherence properties of other sources.
Also: There is a lot of very delicate theory even about Laser linewidth, by pioneers of quantum optics (it was one of the first problems of the emerging field of quantum optics in the 1960s to figure out quantitatively what properties laser light should have). People like Glauber, Townes or Haken are linked to these questions.

Generally, the spectral width is a good proxy for temporal coherence, as in $\tau_c \approx 1/\Delta \nu$. But broadband light doesn't have to be incoherent, it can also just be spectrally broad due to a short pulse length. And then again, of course a pulse can't have a longer coherence length than its length itself.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with xletmjm and Georg E.

Coherence length is related to spectral width

---

To emphasize what is and isn't necessary for interference effect  let me discuss a case that occurs with plain daylight.

When you have a thin film, such as a soap bubble, or a very thin oil film on water, reflexions of the light give rise to color.

Let me take the following case that most people will know from daily life: Some gasoline has been spilled on ground with water puddles. A very thin film of the gasoline spreads out.

When the film thickness is down to the wavelength of visible light you get color effects. The incoming daylight can reflect from the top of the oil film or from the bottom. This multiple reflection gives rise to interference effect. You get selective suppression of specific colors. The color is different in every spot because the thickness of the oil film is different in every spot.

So: if multiple reflection gives rise to interference effects, why don't we see them through every window pane? Well, the window pane is so thick that everything averages out again.

This is crucial for understanding why we *do* see the interference effect in the case of a thin film: there isn't enough room for the interference effect to average out.

So that is the general rule for when you obtain interference effect or not:
If there is enough *room* to average things out you don't get to see interference effect. The thin film is really the only circumstance where *daylight* can give rise to visible interference effect.

Sources of laser light have characteristics that allow you to elicit interference effects in *large setups*.

- The emitter can be set up to be a point source
- The emitter can be set up to produce a narrow spectral line.

Those two conditions are necessary, and sufficient.

Here is why I emphasize this:
Very often people mention that the stimulated emission of laser light gives photons that are all in phase. And it's easy to be tempted into thinking that this all-in-phase property must play a part. But that is not the case. Before laser technology became available interference experiments had been conducted for many decades.

(It was of course very difficult to achieve the two necessary conditions: a point source, and narrow spectral line. For example, a Sodium lamp has high luminosity, so you can shine it towards a screen with a pinhole and what emerges from that pinhole is still sufficient luminosity for your experiment. But a drawback is that that Sodium spectral line is actually a double line, so this won't work for all experiments.)